# What is the equivalent to the R function rep(x, each = n) in Stan?

Tags: stan, rep

In my Stan code, I want to add an ICAR-term (phi) to the following covariate model:

```
// covariate models with logit link
  vector[total_surveys] logit_p = (X_p * beta_p) + phi[ii_sampled];
```

However the `dim(X_p)` = (1900, 3)
and `dim(beta_p)` = 3

Thus `dim(X_p * beta_p` = **1900**

While the `dim(phi[ii_sampled])` is **95**

Therefore, I would like to do:

```
phi_p <- rep(phi[ii_sampled], each = 20)
```

In essence, my problem comes down to doing (example with different dimensions):

```
phi <- c(1.2, -0.5, 2.1, -0.7)
phi_p <- rep(phi, each = 3)

phi_p
>(1.2, 1.2, 1.2, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7)
```

in Stan

Unfortunately, the `rep()` function is not available in Stan. 
You would have to do a loop instead.

What would such a loop look like?

Answer (score 3):

The following is simple and efficient in Stan, because loops in Stan get compiled down to efficient C++ loops.  This could be made shorter, but it'd be less efficient and probably less clear.

```
functions {
  vector rep_each(vector x, int K) {
    int N = rows(x);
    vector[N * K] y;
    int pos = 1;
    for (n in 1:N) {
      for (k in 1:K) {
        y[pos] = x[n];
        pos += 1;
      }
    }
    return y;
  }
}
transformed data {
  print("rep_each([1, 10, 100]', 4) = ",
        rep_each([1, 10, 100]', 4));
}
```

Running this prints

```
rep_each([1, 10, 100]', 4) = [1,1,1,1,10,10,10,10,100,100,100,100]
```